# Generating a kubeconfig file and authenticating for google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes cluster. Inside my cluster is a Django application which needs to connect to my Kubernetes cluster on GKE. Upon my Django start up (inside my Dockerfile), I authenticate with Google Cloud by using:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account $GKE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
gcloud config set project $GKE_PROJECT_NAME
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME --zone $GKE_ZONE
```

I am not really sure if I need to do this everytime my Django container starts, and I am not sure I understand how authentication to Google Cloud works. Could I perhaps just generate my Kubeconfig file, store it somewhere safe and use it all the time instead of authenticating?
In other words, is a Kubeconfig file enough to connect to my GKE cluster?

Comment: How are you connecting to GKE from your app?

Comment: By using the kubernetes library for python. (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), by using a load_kube_config() function inside my python service.

Comment: You can store a kubeconfig file in a secret and mount it as a volume on your pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is running in a Pod inside the GKE cluster you want to connect to, use a Kubernetes service account to authenticate.

1. Create a Kubernetes service account and attach it to your Pod. If your Pod already has a Kubernetes service account, you may skip this step.
2. Use Kubernetes RBAC to grant the Kubernetes service account the correct permissions.

The following example grants **edit** permissions in the **prod** namespace:

```
kubectl create rolebinding yourserviceaccount \
    --clusterrole=edit \
    --serviceaccount=yournamespace:yourserviceaccount\
    --namespace=prod
```

3. At runtime, when your service invokes `kubectl`, it automatically receives the credentials you configured.

You can also store the credentials as a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) and mount it on your pod so that it can read them from there

To use a Secret with your workloads, you can specify environment variables that reference the Secret's values, or mount a volume containing the Secret.

You can create a Secret using the command-line or a YAML file.

Here is an example using Command-line

```
kubectl create secret SECRET_TYPE SECRET_NAME DATA
```

`SECRET_TYPE:` the Secret type, which can be one of the following:

- `generic:`Create a Secret from a local file, directory, or literal value.
- `docker-registry:`Create a `dockercfg` Secret for use with a Docker registry. Used to authenticate against Docker registries.
- `tls:`Create a TLS secret from the given public/private key pair. The public/private key pair must already exist. The public key certificate must be .PEM encoded and match the given private key.

For most Secrets, you use the `generic` type.

`SECRET_NAME:` the name of the Secret you are creating.

`DATA:` the data to add to the Secret, which can be one of the following:

- A path to a directory containing one or more configuration files, indicated using the `--from-file` or `--from-env-file` flags.
- Key-value pairs, each specified using `--from-literal` flags.

If you need more information about `kubectl create` you can check the [reference documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create)

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. One more possible scenario is if we do not use GKE and another provider instead (for example Linode), which as far as I know does not have service accounts like Google Cloud. Would in this case be enough to just store the kubeconfig file somewhere safe and use it from there?

Comment: I found this link that maybe could help you https://www.linode.com/community/questions/20870/kubernetes-authentication-for-additional-non-admin-users